# GNU Makefile and bash - escaping

Tags: gnu-make

In the recipe for a target, I want to generate a bash script which processes command line arguments ... however the Makefile escaping escapes me

target: deps
        echo "./a.out \"$@\"" > wrapper.a.out

However, $@ has a special meaning in a GNU Makefile which messes things up.

Tried $@, $$@ ... nothing appears to work.

So, what is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

```
echo './a.out "$$@"' >wrapper.a.out
```

You need to double the `$` to get it past `make`. then use single quotes in the `echo` command so the shell spawned to run the `echo` doesn't expand `$@` itself.